# How would I pass info between two functions

Tags: reactjs

The DisplayMap has links with id which would show info if user clicked on it. When a user enters '/map' , the map would be centered on their location. if a user goes directly to '/map/21', i would want the map to be centered on the coordinates of the id . How would i send coordinates from Story to DisplayMap

```
function MainStory() {
 let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <DisplayMap pins={pins} />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path}>
          <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>

        </Route>
        <Route path={`${path}/:id`}>
          <Story />

        </Route>
      </Switch>
  );
}

export default MainStory;
```

Comment: You can use context to pass props to elements higher in the tree

Answer (score 0):

You should put the DisplayMap in the Route since it depends on it.

```
const { useParams } = require("react-router-dom")

const SpecificDisplayMap = () => {
    const { id } = useParams()
    const pin = get_pin_by_id(id) // get the specific pin
    return <DisplayMap pins={ [ pin ] } />
}

const MainStory = () => {
    const { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
    return <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path={path}>
                <DisplayMap pins={pins} />
                <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
            </Route>
            <Route path={`${path}/:id`}>
                <DisplayDisplayMap />
                <Story />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    </div>
}

export default MainStory;
```

The get_pin_by_id method can be the same as in the story.

Comment: so I would have to put Displaymap in both routes? one small problem is i would have to change the Link to by removing the '/' in the second route since there are links in DisplayMap. Is <DisplayDIsplayMap> suppose to be SpecificDIsplayMap

Comment: does it make a difference of using function vs const